# Numerically sorting strings from file

Tags: bash

Thing is, I would like to numerically sort those strings from file, without changing content of the file. Strings in file must not be changed after sorting operation. I want to use lines for editing them later, so my variable **var** should get values starting with 0:wc...'till 200:wc. 
Input:

```
11:wc
1:wc 
0:wc
200:wc
```

Desired order:

```
0:wc
1:wc
11:wc
200:wc
```

I'm using this code, but has no effect:

```
sort -k1n $1 | while read line
  do
   if [[ ${line:0:1} != "#" ]] 
    then
    var=$line
   fi
 done <$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort numerically on the first key, and if you need them for later, just read them into an array:

```
myarray=( $(sort -k1n <file) )
```

which will provide an array with sorted contents:

```
0:wc
1:wc
11:wc
200:wc
```

Comment: This works fine :).
How do I igonore, not to print this sorted results in my console?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
$ sort -k1n -t: file.txt
```

specifying the field separator as ':'.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. When you create a pipe, such as `command | while read line; do ... end`, the individual commands in the pipe (`command` and `while read line; do ... end`) run in *subshells*.

   The subshells are created with copies of all the current variables, but are not able to reflect changes back into their parent. In this case `line` is only present in the subshell, and when the subshell terminates, it disappears with it.

   You can use bash process substitution to avoid creating a subshell for one of the pipeline commands. For example, you could use:

   ```
    while read line; do ... end < <(command)
   ```
2. If you both pipe and redirect, the redirect wins.

   So when you write: `command | while read line; do ... end < input`, the while loop actually reads from `input`, not from the output of command.